# Amazon linux package conflict

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum, php-fpm, bug, amazon-linux

I was trying install php55-fpm on amazon linux, but there is a package conflict with php-common. How solve this issue ?

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-12-54 ~]$ sudo yum install php55-fpm
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                                | 2.3 kB     00:00     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php55-fpm.x86_64 0:5.5.7-1.61.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php55-common(x86-64) = 5.5.7-1.61.amzn1 for package: php55-fpm-5.5.7-1.61.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php55-common.x86_64 0:5.5.7-1.61.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php55-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) for package: php55-common-5.5.7-1.61.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libzip.so.2()(64bit) for package: php55-common-5.5.7-1.61.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libzip.x86_64 0:0.10.1-1.3.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php55-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.9.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/pecl for package: php55-pecl-jsonc-1.3.2-1.9.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjson-c.so.2()(64bit) for package: php55-pecl-jsonc-1.3.2-1.9.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package json-c.x86_64 0:0.11-4.5.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php-pear.noarch 1:1.9.4-20.15.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-20.15.amzn1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-posix for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-20.15.amzn1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-xml for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-20.15.amzn1.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.28-1.2.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.28-1.2.amzn1 for package: php-cli-5.3.28-1.2.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package php-process.x86_64 0:5.3.28-1.2.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.3.28-1.2.amzn1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.28-1.2.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php55-common-5.5.7-1.61.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.7-1.61.amzn1
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php55-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.28-1.2.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-12-54 ~]$ cat /etc/issue
Amazon Linux AMI release 2013.09
Kernel \r on an \m
```

This is a new Amazon linux box. There is no php at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here we see that the dependencies are trying to bring in `php-pear`, which depends on `php-common`, which is the wrong version; I would be expecting `php55-common`, and possibly `php55-pear` packages to be pulled in here.

This isn't something you can really resolve; the repository you're trying to install from has broken packages. (Unfortunately this poor quality packaging is all too common with Amazon Linux, which is one reason I recommend against using it.) You'll need to contact Amazon, or better yet, use anything but Amazon Linux.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the output. See the edited answer.